# Ace Editor autocomplete and multiple languages

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, ace-editor

How can I create an autocomplete and how to highlight html, javascript and css inside php for the Ace editor http://ace.ajax.org/.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?=$title; ?></title>
        <style>
            body {
                background: black;
                color: white;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            alert("this is only a no-sense test script....");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        This is only a no-sense test script but I want that html tags, css styles and javascript code are highlighted....<br />
        Is it possible?
    </body>
</html>
```

(sorry for my english)

Comment: Is this actually a feature request for the ace editor? Apart from that, highlighting code within php code is supposedly something wickedly difficult. I use Aptana, which I think is a very fine and enhanced IDE, but even that doesn't highlight html code in say an echo php-statement...

Comment: i do not want to highlight code inside strings....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two questions.

1. How can I create an autocompleter that completes PHP?
2. How can I syntax highlight HTLM code inside PHP code?

For the second question, there is some discussion in the [Google group for Ace Editor](http://groups.google.com/group/ace-discuss/browse_thread/thread/432dbb1ed69808c4/4b44e36e4592f7c8?lnk=gst&q=syntax%20highlight%20html%20inside%20php#4b44e36e4592f7c8) In my opinion, the question is not really answered if it is possible or not, but it seems at least doable. Have a look at the [documentation for highlighter](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Creating-or-Extending-an-Edit-Mode), especially about the part "Embedding a different highlighter".

For autocompletion, I don't see a chance at all. See the [Google group entry](http://groups.google.com/group/ace-discuss/browse_thread/thread/f8657d5ec2b7ed49) about a similar (recent) question.

Comment: no... the questions are: 1. autocomplete php code 2.highlight html, javascript and css code inside php

Answer (score 2):

As of a few months ago the Ace Editor now supports autocomplete (see: http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about)

Answer (score 0):

For any one still looking around for this, I found exactly what I needed here: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/How-to-enable-Autocomplete-in-the-Ace-editor

I wanted to enable live auto-completion, so there is another option `enableLiveAutocompletion` and `enableSnippets` (to give a brief description of the suggestion if available).

I used it like this:

```
editor.setOptions({
     enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
     enableSnippets: true
 });
```

There is also an example demonstrating how you could add a custom completer to return results tailored to your specific project.