# Autocompletion in ACE editor

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, syntax-highlighting, ace-editor

I've found simmilar question: [Ace Editor autocomplete and multiple languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938985/ace-editor-autocomplete-and-multiple-languages)

But the responses were that autocompletion is not supported by ACE, and according to  [Google group for Ace Editor](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ace-discuss/Qy27HtaYCMQ%5C) "It is on my wishlish for Ace and we definitively need it
for Cloud9".

This post is one year old and as you can see, the cloud9 supports autocompletion now:
https://c9.io/site/features/

So is autocompletion available in Ace Editor by default? I cannot find any information about it.

Comment: Related question: [How to add my own completer in ace editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44276794/how-to-add-my-own-completer-in-ace-editor)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Autocomplete is now an official part of the API.  Enabling it takes 3 lines of code:

```
ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setOptions({
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true
});
```

Depending on your setup with require-js, you may also need to include an additional javascript file in the html for your page:

```
<script src="ace/ext-language_tools.js"></script>
```

You can find a demo at https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/demo/autocompletion.html

And here's the wiki page I just wrote on the topic:

https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/How-to-enable-Autocomplete-in-the-Ace-editor

Comment: this is very good, but just a quick question, where is the rest of the documentation ? i want to write some snippets for latex and im stuck, how would i write snippets for something like \begin{... which can have 10 different things after it?  see the possibilities here: https://github.com/mercutiodesign/texmaker-3.3.3/blob/master/completion/completion.txt

Comment: I can't believe there is no better documentation for this on the official site... thanks a lot, I searched really long until I found your answer

Comment: The `setOptions()` method didn't work for me. I had to use, `editor.setOption("enableBasicAutocompletion", true);`. FYI I'm using it in an application wrapper with proxy objects so there may be something lost in translation.

Comment: @mike see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65219943/2750743) below - you can pass object implementing `getCompletions()` instead of boolean in `enableBasicAutocompletion`.

Answer (score 21):

Since Autocomplete is now a part of the [ACE](http://ace.c9.io/) api:

1) Include [ace.js](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/ace.js) at the top of your html:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ace.js"></script>
```

2) Also include your [mode](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/tree/01387134306d44415871cbb9da91652b752f195f/src) (language type):

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mode-yaml.js"></script>
```

3) Also include your [theme](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/01387134306d44415871cbb9da91652b752f195f/src-noconflict/theme-monokai.js):

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/theme-monokai.js"></script>
```

4) Also include [ex-language_tools.js](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/01387134306d44415871cbb9da91652b752f195f/src/ext-language_tools.js):

```
  <script src="js/ext-language_tools.js"></script>
```

5) Add your div with id editor (this will become your [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)):

```
  <div id="editor"></div>
```

6) Include the following script (see my comments to understand them) :

```
  <script>
    var langTools = ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
```

Line below transforms your div with id="editor" into the editor

```
  var editor = ace.edit("editor");
```

Line below sets the color theme. Other themes available [here](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/tree/01387134306d44415871cbb9da91652b752f195f/src)...try them [here](http://ace.c9.io/tool/mode_creator.html)

```
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
```

Line below sets the mode based on programming language...other modes here:

```
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/yaml");


    editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
```

Lines below turns ON autocompletion in real-time.

```
editor.setOptions({
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableSnippets: true,
    enableLiveAutocompletion: false
});
```

**Thus, the whole thing could be broken down into the following:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>IDE AUTOCOMPLETE</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ace.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mode-yaml.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/theme-monokai.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ext-language_tools.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- EDITOR SECTION BELOW! -->
  <div id="editor"></div>
  <script>
    var langTools = ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/yaml");
    editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
    editor.setOptions({
        enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
        enableSnippets: true,
        enableLiveAutocompletion: false
    });
  </script>
  <!-- EDITOR SECTION ABOVE -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to call `setOption()` rather than `setOptions({enableBasicAutocompletion: true})`. I used editor.getOptions() and editor.getOption("enableBasicAutocompletion") to check that the value was actually set and it all worked with `editor.setOption("enableBasicAutocompletion", true);`

Comment: This worked for me as of July 26, 2018 with Ace v1.3.3. `enableLiveAutocompletion: false` makes it necessary to hit Ctrl + Space to show suggestions. `enableLiveAutocompletion: true` shows suggestions after typing some letters. Also not all the modes have suggestions: for instance, `html` has, while `pascal` does not have.

Answer (score 12):

Note, to implement custom completion logic, you can pass a completion provider object in `enableBasicAutocompletion`.

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/klesun/e48d75np/1/)

```html
<!-- integrity removed for example sake -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.12/ace.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.12/ext-language_tools.js"></script>

<script>
const editor = ace.edit('some-ace-editor-holder-div-id');
editor.setOptions({
  enableBasicAutocompletion: [{
    getCompletions: (editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) => {
      // note, won't fire if caret is at a word that does not have these letters
      callback(null, [
        {value: 'hello', score: 1, meta: 'some comment'},
        {value: 'world', score: 2, meta: 'some other comment'},
      ]);
    },
  }],
  // to make popup appear automatically, without explicit _ctrl+space_
  enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
});
</script>
```

[image]

Info [source](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace/issues/69#issuecomment-354134011)

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44772708/2750743) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24652084/2750743) answers

Answer (score 10):

Autocompletion is still not available natively for Ace, however we have implemented a component doing that for the [Codiad IDE](http://codiad.com/) which is based on Ace and fully open source.
You can check the code on [Github](https://github.com/Codiad/Codiad/blob/master/components/autocomplete/init.js), it will surely help you to write your own.

Comment: I can see some great piece of work over there. I've had a look into your `init.js` file. Could you please help me as to *how* this thing is integrated into Ace? Where/How is it being loaded?

Comment: It is not integrated _into_ Ace as such, see it more like a component that we add on top of it. We intercept the keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+Space) and open a popup that we fill with suggestions. We use the Ace api to get the text from the document to build the suggestions and to eventually insert the suggestion text. Have a look at the 'keybindings' component, it might help a bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions! I'll definitely have a look into it. :-)

Comment: Note, this statement is not true anymore. Ace does provide completion functionality  nowadays with `language_tools` extension enabled through [`enableBasicAutocompletion`](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace/issues/69#issuecomment-354134011) option.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to have following imports

```
require('ace/ext/language_tools');
```

Use under snippet as required

```
editor.setOptions({
            enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
            enableSnippets: true,
            enableLiveAutocompletion: true
        });
```

Comment: Why do you need multi_select?

Comment: @Jamessaystrytopanswers.xyz I don't remeber exactly, but I think you are right we dont need multi_select. I guess I copied it too while pasting answer

Answer (score 3):

**AjaxOrg** has pushed a commit in their **Cloud9** repository with the following message:

> Code completion plug-in

I assume that this would be the answer to this question.

[**Here**](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/commit/09f2ada631c07e1ed1925916c959f6903215f93d) is the commit.

---

Also, I think that [**this**](https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin-editor) is a good project that can help us.

For more information, we can follow the message from [**this issue opened in Cloud9 repository**](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/110).

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not available in any form. According to this issue:
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/1031

Autocomplete is only available in Cloud9 IDE (which is based on ACE) and may be available **later** as a separate plugin for ACE Editor.

Comment: Could you please tell me additional 2 things: Is not cloud9 open source (or some of its functionality is not open source?) and not to create separate question - if you know - what library is the cloud9 gui written in ?

Comment: 1) Yes, some functionality isn't open source
2) They're using own framework for UI - http://ui.ajax.org/

Comment: The gherkin editor based on Ace seems to have it.  https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin-editor/blob/master/public/js/gherkin-editor/autocomplete.js

Comment: Yep, but this haven't updated for a long time and I'm not sure it's compatible with current ACE version. And this is just basic autocomplete **engine** for ACE - so you'll have to write autocompletion options for each language to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your mounted:

```
this.aceEditor.setOptions({
        enableSnippets: true,
        enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
        enableBasicAutocompletion: true
      })
```

Comment: Please add some explanation about why these lines could help.