# Destroy an open autocomplete popup in Ace editor

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, ace-editor

I'm using the [Ace Editor](http://ace.c9.io/) with [autocompletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545433/autocompletion-in-ace-editor) turned on. The editor appears in a modal frame on the page.

If the modal frame is closed (i.e. the editor is removed from the DOM) while an autocomplete popup is open, the popup gets stuck and can't be closed. **What's the right way to destroy the popup?**

The best I've found so far is

```
editor.completer.detach();
```

This seems to work, but it's undocumented and I don't know if there are any side-effects or concerns. Is there a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

detach is the right method, since it is what is called when pressing esc key see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/60c639a34bc4a44ec84484f99bdd879177179b87/lib/ace/autocomplete.js#L207