# How to display autocomplete choices in swagger-editor

Tags: swagger-editor

How do you get autocomplete to work in the YAML editor view of swagger-editor?  I see `autoComplete: true` in preferences.js.  What do you need to do in the editor to get the snippet to appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  swagger-editor sets `enableLiveAutocompletion: true` for the ACE editor (app/scripts/services/editor.js).  For some reason, this disables live auto completion(!)  Setting it to false enables it.  Now as I type I can see the autocompletion selections and can insert snippets.  Strange that this option seems reversed.

Thanks to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27828826/2525213 for helping me figure this out.