# How to add my own completer in ace editor

Tags: ace-editor

Now i am developing a simple web-based editor for my database backend. I found that [ace](https://ace.c9.io) comes with autocompleter, if I only need to do complete with SQL keywords, how should I add my own rules?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, Activate the *enableLiveAutocompletion* as you mentioned, and you also have to ensure `enableBasicAutocompletion` is defined and set to `true` (see below).

```
editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/sql");
editor.setOptions({
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableSnippets: true,
    enableLiveAutocompletion: true
});
```

To add a new completer, do what **eemp** mentioned on github ([here](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace/issues/69)).

```
let langTools = ace.require('ace/ext/language_tools');
```

Then use the `addCompleter` method to add the completions as defined below:

```
var customCompleter = {
  getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
       // your code
       /* for example
        * let TODO = ...;
        * callback(null, [{name: TODO, value: TODO, score: 1, meta: TODO}]);
        */
  }

 }
langTools.addCompleter(customCompleter);
```

You can also go have a look at the following:

[Ace docs on Completers](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/How-to-enable-Autocomplete-in-the-Ace-editor).

Comment: `langTools.addCompleter(customCompleter)` presumably creates a _global_ completer. To attach the completer to the ace editor itself, use `editor.completers = [customCompleter]`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

```
editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/sql");
editor.setOptions({
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableSnippets: true,
    enableLiveAutocompletion: true
});
```

the *enableLiveAutocompletion* attribute will allow realtime popup