# How to specify a list of custom tokens to list for autocompletion in Ace Editor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ace-editor, react-ace

After following the setup for autocompletion with [Ace Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545433/autocompletion-in-ace-editor), I have it working with [react-ace](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace). However, I need some custom tokens to be available in the built-in autocomplete list.

The repository for `react-ace` has these properties defined as

```
enableBasicAutocompletion: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.bool, PropTypes.array]),
enableLiveAutocompletion: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.bool, PropTypes.array]),
```

but what is this `array` ?

I have tried setting `enableBasicAutocompletion={ ['custom'] }`, and `enableBasicAutocompletion={ [ (...args) => console.log(args) ] }` but both fails with an error about `getCompletions not a function`.

How can I add these custom autocomplete keywords to the list?

```
<AceEditor
    name={ this.uniqueName }
    mode="javascript"
    theme="github"
    onChange={ onChange }
    enableBasicAutocompletion
    enableLiveAutocompletion
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use editor.completers array to add a new completer that returns the completions you want

```
editor.completers.push({
    getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
        var completions = [];
        // we can use session and pos here to decide what we are going to show
        ["word1", "word2"].forEach(function(w) {

            completions.push({
                value: w,
                meta: "my completion",

            });
        });
        callback(null, completions);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just import this!

```js
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/ext-language_tools"
```

And write this code in your render function

```
<AceEditor
    mode="java"
    theme="github"
    onChange={onChange}
    name="UNIQUE_ID_OF_DIV"
    editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
    setOptions={{
      enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
      enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
      enableSnippets: true
    }}
```

Comment: Please could you pad your answer out a bit - there were a few questions/clarifications needed that could be helpful.